# square wave frequency doesn't change smoothly

Tags: java, audio, javasound

I wrote a little square wave generator. Whenever i try to change the frequency smoothly there are always clearly audible "steps" in the sound. I'm pretty sure there is a quite obvious solution which i am failing to see:(

code:

```
double rate = 44100;
byte[] buffer;
AudioFormat audioFormat;

buffer = new byte[1];
audioFormat = new AudioFormat((float) rate, 8, 1, true, false);

SourceDataLine sourceDataLine = AudioSystem.getSourceDataLine(audioFormat);
sourceDataLine.open(audioFormat);
sourceDataLine.start();

int i = 0;
boolean on = false;
while (!t.isInterrupted())
{
    i++;
    if (i < rate / frequency)
    {
        i++;
    } else
    {
        i = 0;
        on = !on;
    }
    if (on)
        buffer[0] = (byte) (volume / 2);
    else
        buffer[0] = (byte) (-volume / 2);
    sourceDataLine.write(buffer, 0, 1);
}
sourceDataLine.drain();
sourceDataLine.stop();
sourceDataLine.close();
```

Comment: Swing code doesn't have anything do to with this question. Please remove it.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you are only using an 8 bit sample size. This only gives you 256 sound levels which is not enough to give smooth changes. Use 16 bit samples to get 64k levels.

Comment: OP is generating a square wave which is a rectangular function. There is no need to increase the sample size because the change between hi & lo is immediate e.g. |⎺⎺|__|⎺⎺|__|

Answer (score 1):

If you just change the frequency like

```
frequency=440.0;
```

you are implicitly changing the phase of the signal too.
Think: the function sin(440x) has a different value at x=10 then sin(442x).
This difference is heard as a popping sound. To prevent this you have to adjust the phase of the signal (In your case the 'i' variable, I changed it to 'phase' below) by the factor oldFrequency/newFrequency.
You also need to change your code a bit for this to work:

```
double phase=0;
public void setFrequency(double newFrequency){
  phase*=frequency/newFrequency;
  freqency=newFrequency;
}
public void run(){
  //...
  while(!t.isInterrupted()){
    phase++;
    if (phase > rate / frequency)  //flipped inequality sign!
    {
      phase %= rate / frequency;
      on = !on;
    }
    //...
  }
}
```

PS: You should also probably increase your buffer size. A buffer is also used to maintain signal smoothness, by calculating the signal in advance. A good buffer size would be 200.